# What deities are common knowledge along the northern parts of the Sword Coast? (post-1480 DR)

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, forgotten-realms, religions-and-deities

Specifically between Neverwinter and Icewind Dale, which religions are common knowledge in the years following 1480 DR?

Common knowledge being that if a player character grew up in this area, they would realistically already know that that deity is a deity and maybe something about their religion.

Example: When asked, the average person in the region may say "Mystra is the deity of Magic" if Mystra and her religion are common knowledge.

Comment: It may help us give better answers if you can explain the reason for asking; what's the game issue you're encountering that this information is relevant to? Otherwise, answers could be really well-researched, but fail to address the thing you really want to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deities in the Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide are known by the common people. Quoting (page 19):

> The various races of Toril worship their pantheons, which remain largely the same from region to region, with different cultures and societies emphasizing some deities over others. Although exceptions exist-the gods of Mulhorand, for example-all the gods are revered across all of Faerun.

Particularly the Faerunian pantheon are all known and worshipped by the average person. There is a separate section "New and Foreign Gods", which is also an indication that the Faerunian pantheon is "well-established".